# If I download the ISO file, will it delete Windows?

Tags: windows, downloads, external-hdd

I have a Laptop computer with no operating system on it. I want to use my sister's computer with Windows 10, just to download the ISO file on an external drive and then install Ubuntu on my own computer. Is it possible to download Ubuntu on an external drive without installing it? I see some programs start the installing process after download, but I dont want it to happen. The installation will be on my own computer. I dont want the download to cause problems on my sister's computer after downloading Ubuntu.

Comment: have you ever downloaded a file that would delete windows after it was downloaded?

Comment: I think you should just get Virtual Box or VM Ware first and install it as virtual machine. This will give you practice, and when you feel confident - do real installation. As for iso files, it's just like any other file - download and save it. It won't  install by itself. Read tutorials and documentation, that will help,too.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Ubuntu, so I am voting to close. As to answer your question, Ubuntu does not contain an .exe file like windows iso's do, as it is not built around NTFS, so if Windows mounted the ISO file, nothing would happen

Answer (score 1):

The ISO file is not an executable, so just downloading it won't cause any issues. The proper way to install is to burn the ISO onto a disk and boot up your computer from it. Moreover, when you start the installation process, it will provide you with options for configuring the install. You will always be able to back out of the installation process until you actually push the install button.